# How to end Function if the Cancel Button is clicked in a "GetSaveAsFileName" - Dialog in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I want to end my macro if the user clicks on `Cancel` or `X` in this code:

```
Dim TargetFile As String

TargetFile = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(FileFilter:="AVL (*.rtf), *.rtf", 
InitialFileName:="AVL.rtf")
```

The macro runs now, even though I press `cancel` or `X` .

How would you adjust the code to end the macro if `cancel` or `X` is pressed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [Official Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-getsaveasfilename-method-excel) for `Application.GetSaveAsFilename`

> This method returns the selected file name or the name entered by the user. The returned name may include a path specification. Returns **False** if the user cancels the dialog box.

So:

```
Dim TargetFile As Variant

TargetFile = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(FileFilter:="AVL (*.rtf), *.rtf", _
    InitialFileName:="AVL.rtf")
If (TargetFile = False) Then Exit Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The problem is, that later in my macro I am writing into the TargetFile, so it has to be a String, or am I wrong here?

Comment: A [`Variant`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/variant-data-type) is a "special" data type - you can put `String`, `Boolean`, `Decimal`, `Long`, `Object`, etc in there.  Think of it as an "I need some sort of variable, but I don't know what data will be in there yet" option.  This is useful, because `Application.GetSaveAsFilename` returns a `Variant` as either a `String` (the filename selected) or a `Boolean` (`False`, when you click `Cancel`)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. The code runs in a Public Function, so I thought, i have to change your Exit Sub to Exit Function. If I implement it like this, the macro does not exit the function and runs through when cancel is clicked.

Comment: I put it like this: If(TargetFile = False) Then End. This is working. Do you think, there are any issues with that?

Comment: Using `End` will stop everything, but `Exit Function` will resume the procedure that called your function.