# Exit For Each Loop on Cancel of Save Dialog Box

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA and as part of my own development I'm currently in the process of re-writing some automation I wrote to completion some 6+ months ago.  I have the below code which identifies the sheet name based on which sheet a button is pushed (there are two different sheet names similar to `CustName_CALC` and two buttons). It then goes through the remaining sheets in the workbook to find "similar" sheets.

The below sub `PDF_Bill()` is applied to the before mentioned buttons:

```
Public vPDFilename As Variant
Public wb As Workbook
Public ws As Worksheet
Public wsBill As Worksheet
Public wsCalc As Worksheet
Public wsStatement As Worksheet
Public sLocation As String, sCustName As String, myTitle As String, myMsg As String, InitialFileName As String, Response As String, C_Response As String

Sub PDF_Bill()

sCustName = Left(ActiveSheet.Name, InStr(ActiveSheet.Name, "_") - 1)

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set wsCalc = wb.Sheets(sCustName & "_CALC")

myTitle = "Save Invoice"
myMsg = "Are you sure you would like to save the " & wsCalc.Cells(1, 2).Value2 & " invoice?"
Response = MsgBox(myMsg, vbQuestion + vbOKCancel, myTitle)
Select Case Response
    Case Is = vbOK

For Each wsBill In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If wsBill.Name Like sCustName & "_BILL" & "*" Then
                    Call Module1_PDF.PDF_Procedure
        End If       
    Next wsBill

    Case Is = vbCancel
        'user cancels the first popup message
        myTitle = "Invoice Cancelled!"
        myMsg = "You've cancelled the request to save the invoice!"
        C_Response = MsgBox(myMsg, vbOKOnly, myTitle)

End Select
End Sub
```

The above calls this:

```
Sub PDF_Procedure()

sCustName = Left(ActiveSheet.Name, InStr(ActiveSheet.Name, "_") - 1)
sLocation = "S:DRIVELOCATION" & wsCalc.Cells(1, 2).Value2 & "\Invoices\"

vPDFilename = Application.GetSaveAsFilename( _
InitialFileName:=sLocation _
                    & wsCalc.Cells(1, 2).Value2 _
                    & " " _
                    & MonthName(Month(Date)) _
                    & " Invoice", _
FileFilter:="PDF, *.pdf", _
Title:="Save as PDF")

If vPDFilename <> False Then
    With wsBill
        '.Visible = xlSheetVisible '[will be hidden at later state]
        '.Activate
        'predefined area for 5 page invoice - this may need to change in future.
        .PageSetup.PrintArea = "A1:S300"
    End With

    'creates the PDF
    wsBill.ExportAsFixedFormat _
    Type:=xlTypePDF, _
    Filename:=vPDFilename, _
    OpenAfterPublish:=False

    'wsBill.Visible = xlSheetHidden 'bill sheet HIDE [WILL BE USED LATER NOT SET UP]
    Else
      'if user cancels save dialog box
      myTitle = "Invoice Cancelled!"
      myMsg = "You've cancelled the request to save the invoice!"
      C_Response = MsgBox(myMsg, vbOKOnly, myTitle)
      wsCalc.Activate
      GoTo CancelProcess    
End If
CancelProcess:
Exit Sub
End Sub
```

The above code (with the exception of the `GoTo CancelProcess` since that is what I'm struggling with) works perfectly for one sheet called `CustName_Bill` but I also need it to work for the below scenario.

I have reviewed the following pages and more without success:

- [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50906066/how-to-end-function-if-the-cancel-button-is-clicked-in-a-getsaveasfilename-d)
- [and here](https://bettersolutions.com/vba/functions/goto-statement.htm)

I know I need an `exit` statement somewhere, but I'm struggling to understand where it goes. A lot of the examples I've seen aren't complex enough to lead me to a conclusion how to resolve my issue.

My issue currently is that I have two sheets which are named similar (on purpose):

- CustName_Bill_Type
- CustName_Bill_Type1

the loop continues onto the next sheet ie `CustName_Bill_Type1` when the user cancels the `Application.GetSaveAsFilename` but I need the `for each` loop to exit when the user cancels the **first** `Application.GetSaveAsFilename` dialog box.

So my question is, where do I need to put my `exit` to get the code to completely terminate as soon as the user clicks cancel on the **first** save dialog box.

Comment: Do you want the entire macro to terminate when the user selects Cancel, or is there any cleanup you need to do? If the former, you can simply use `End`.

Comment: the entire macro should terminate when the user selects Cancel on the save dialog box. Please clarify what you mean by "simply use end".

Comment: `Case Is = vbCancel Exit Sub`

Comment: @MG92 please advise where this goes. Please note that is my actual question "where do I need to put my exit". edit: `Case is = vbCancel` would only exit at the message box rather than the save dialog, would it not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert the sub to a function so that you can return FALSE if the user cancelled the save.

```vb
Function PDF_Procedure() as Boolean

    sCustName = Left(ActiveSheet.Name, InStr(ActiveSheet.Name, "_") - 1)
    sLocation = "S:DRIVELOCATION" & wsCalc.Cells(1, 2).Value2 & "\Invoices\"

    vPDFilename = Application.GetSaveAsFilename( _
    InitialFileName:=sLocation _
                        & wsCalc.Cells(1, 2).Value2 _
                        & " " _
                        & MonthName(Month(Date)) _
                        & " Invoice", _
    FileFilter:="PDF, *.pdf", _
    Title:="Save as PDF")

    If vPDFilename <> False Then
        With wsBill
            '.Visible = xlSheetVisible '[will be hidden at later state]
            '.Activate
            'predefined area for 5 page invoice - this may need to change in future.
            .PageSetup.PrintArea = "A1:S300"
        End With

        'creates the PDF
        wsBill.ExportAsFixedFormat _
        Type:=xlTypePDF, _
        Filename:=vPDFilename, _
        OpenAfterPublish:=False

        ' return true if saved
        PDF_Procedure = True   
        'wsBill.Visible = xlSheetHidden 'bill sheet HIDE [WILL BE USED LATER NOT SET UP]
    Else
        'if user cancels save dialog box
        myTitle = "Invoice Cancelled!"
        myMsg = "You've cancelled the request to save the invoice!"
        C_Response = MsgBox(myMsg, vbOKOnly, myTitle)
        wsCalc.Activate

        'return false if cancelled
        PDF_Procedure = False   
    End If

End Function
```

and add a condition to your PDF_Bill sub

```vb
For Each wsBill In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If wsBill.Name Like sCustName & "_BILL" & "*" Then
        If Module1_PDF.PDF_Procedure() = False Then
            Exit sub
        End if
    End If       
Next wsBill
```

Comment: Interesting take on the result! Thanks for you answer.

Comment: Hmm - trying to apply your answer and i'm getting a syntax error on `If Module1_PDF.PDF_Procedure() = False`. Thought I mistyped something so I've copied directly from your answer and still getting the syntax error. @CDP1802

Comment: @unbeknown looks like I forgot the THEN

Comment: Perfect! Works like a charm, and much cleaner than my solution!

Answer (score 0):

Well after spending several hours more looking at this and more testing I have figured it out!

Moved the `GoTo` from the `PDF_Procedure()` sub to `PDF_Bill()` sub and added a boolean `bCancelled`

```
bCancelled = false
For Each wsBill In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
     If bCancelled = True Then GoTo CancelProcess
        If wsBill.Name Like sCustName & "_BILL" & "*" Then
                    Call Module_PDF.PDF_Procedure
        End If
    Next wsBill

'Call Module_CopyData.StatementData 'copy bill info to wsStatement

    Case Is = vbCancel
        'user cancels the first popup message
        myTitle = "Invoice Cancelled!"
        'myMsg = "You've cancelled the request to save the invoice!"
        myMsg = "Select Case"
        C_Response = MsgBox(myMsg, vbOKOnly, myTitle)
End Select

CancelProcess:
 If bCancelled = True Then
    'if user cancels save dialog box
    myTitle = "Invoice Cancelled!"
    'myMsg = "You've cancelled the request to save the invoice!"
    myMsg = "CancelProcess"
    C_Response = MsgBox(myMsg, vbOKOnly, myTitle)
    wsCalc.Activate
```

And in sub `PDF_Procedure()

```
If vPDFilename <> False Then
    With wsBill
        .Visible = xlSheetVisible
        '.Activate
        'predefined area for 5 page invoice - this may need to change in future.
        .PageSetup.PrintArea = "A1:S300"
    End With

    'creates the PDF
    wsBill.ExportAsFixedFormat _
    Type:=xlTypePDF, _
    Filename:=vPDFilename, _
    OpenAfterPublish:=False
    'wsBill.Visible = xlSheetHidden 'bill sheet HIDE

    Else
        bCancelled = True

End If
```